# Installing WP in Bitnami with php 7

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to test possible incompatibilities of my WordPress site with php 7.
So I downloaded the php 7 [wamp installer](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp/installer) and installed it without problems.

Then I downloaded the [WordPress module](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp/modules)

But when I try to install it, i get this message [image: yo]

The installation is completed and I can see the WP files, but when I go to the supposed site address it says "The requested URL /wordpress was not found on this server."

Is there any solution. Has anyone managed to install WP on a php 7 Bitnami?
And are there any known problems when trying to install WP with php 7?

Comment: "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()" - The mysql extension was removed in PHP 7 (it was formerly deprecated in PHP 5.5, although the recommendation to avoid using it has been around for years). I'm pretty sure a default https://wordpress.org install does not use the mysql extension. The code would need to be changed to use the MySQLi or PDO extensions instead. Although you could try migrating your existing database and codebase?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the hope :-) I will try it online in a test domain I guess.

Comment: You're welcome. Just to add, a default WP install doesn't create a database - this is something you would normally do manually in your server config (which this Bitnami script is trying to do for you). You could try creating the DB manually and rerunning a WP install? AFAIK, the latest WP works OK on PHP 7. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/09/10/wordpress-and-php7/